# migration from Progress DB to MySQL using linux

Tags: mysql, database, migration

I am trying to replicate a Progress database to MySQL 5.1..now , I came across a few softwares and a few suggestions on stackoverflow as well as other websites which necessitate the involvement of a Software like Pro2SQL or other SQL migration tools like MySQL migration tool.But the problem that i am faced with is that I will be using Linux to run the mysql.i am working on linux.Is there a software for linux(I am using bash scripting to query the MYSQL database) or another other means?

Currently , I am using jdbc to connect and retrieve, but mapping the database is hard and may create flaws in the long run due to mapping problems.Also, this proccess will be repeated  quiet often..for backup.
Since, MySQL migration tool is a good solution , but it doesnt support linux command prompt, so I have to implement in another better / optimized way..Please suggest what should be done further.Thanks a ton for the support..

Answer (score 0):

**If it is just about dumping :**

If i get your problem the solution holds in two lines (If you are following SQL standards) :

```
 pg_dump <yourdatabase>

 mysql < <yourfile.sql>
```

With the first line you are dumping your database, many options exists whether you want to dump tables, content, schemas, etc... go to the man page for more details

With the second lines you are just loading them into your mysql.

**If it is about mapping :**

Take a look a [Kettle](http://kettle.pentaho.com/), it's an Open Source ETL, it works really well on Linux and you can automize task using crontabs.

Hope I could help,